# How do I read a whole folder of filled PDF forms and transfer the values into a csv table?

Tags: python, pdf, export-to-csv

I have a folder of PDF forms that have 6 fillable fields. How do I make a script that can read all of them, grab the values, and add each form's values as a new record in a CSV file?

So far, I've managed to use PyPDF2 to read a single file and input all the values into a dictionary.

This is my code:

```
import PyPDF2
import csv
f = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('form.pdf')
ff = f.getFields()
```

This is the output:

```
>>> ff
{'Name': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Name', '/V': 'Mike'},
'Favourite Colour': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Favourite Colour', '/V': 'Blue'},
'Favourite Food': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Favourite Food', '/V': "Apple"},
'Y/N': {'/FT': '/Ch', '/T': 'Y/N', '/Ff': 131072, '/V': 'Yes', '/DV': '-'},
'Number of Siblings': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Number of Siblings', '/V': '2'},
'Phone Number': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Phone Number', '/V': '829-555-5555'}}
```

Then, I used get() to extract the values I need:

```
gg = {}
gg['Name'] = ff.get('Name').get('/V')
gg['Favourite Colour'] = ff.get('Favourite Colour').get('/V')
gg['Favourite Food'] = ff.get('Favourite Food').get('/V')
gg['Y/N'] = ff.get('Y/N').get('/V')
gg['Number of Siblings'] = ff.get('Number of Siblings').get('/V')
gg['Phone Number'] = ff.get('Phone Number').get('/V')
```

Which gave me:

```
>>> gg
{'Name': 'Mike', 'Favourite Colour': 'Blue', 'Favourite Food': 'Apple', 'Y/N': 'Yes', 'Number of Siblings': '10', 'Phone Number': '829-555-5555'}
```

But now I don't know how to print this to a CSV. The problem also is I have dozens of these filled PDF forms, so I can't just change `f = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('form.pdf')` and do this one by one.

Is there a way I can read a whole folder of filled PDF forms and print each form's values as a unique record in a CSV?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict`-comprehension to make data extraction cleaner, i.e.:

```
ff = {'Name': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Name', '/V': 'Mike'},
'Favourite Colour': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Favourite Colour', '/V': 'Blue'},
'Favourite Food': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Favourite Food', '/V': "Apple"},
'Y/N': {'/FT': '/Ch', '/T': 'Y/N', '/Ff': 131072, '/V': 'Yes', '/DV': '-'},
'Number of Siblings': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Number of Siblings', '/V': '2'},
'Phone Number': {'/FT': '/Tx', '/T': 'Phone Number', '/V': '829-555-5555'}}
gg = {k:v['/V'] for k,v in ff.items()}
print(gg)
```

output:

```
{'Name': 'Mike', 'Favourite Colour': 'Blue', 'Favourite Food': 'Apple', 'Y/N': 'Yes', 'Number of Siblings': '2', 'Phone Number': '829-555-5555'}
```

Note that we do not have to hardcode fields doing it this way. If all files you wan tot process have names ending with `.pdf` and there is not any file have such name and is not actually pdf file you might harness `glob` built-in module, before you will use it for processing please check if following:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    print(filename)
```

does output all files you want to process. For writing CSV file you might harness [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) from built-in module `csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You're three quarters of the way there.

Create a function to wrap what you've done so far. Give it a good name like `pdf_form_field_values(pdf_path)`. This will, for a given pdf filepath, return a dictionary.

You also need to create a loop over all the pdfs in the folder. You can use [**`glob`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for that.

You can write to a csv file using a [**`csv.DictWriter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter). If you want a header, you can tell the writer to create it. You also tell the writer what order you want the columns.

Putting it all together:

```
from glob import glob
import csv

with io.open('results.csv', mode='w', newline='') as output:
    columns = ['Name', 'Favourite Colour', 'Favourite Food', 'Y/N',
               'Number of Siblings', 'Phone Number']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, columns)

    writer.writeheader()  # optional

    for pdf_path in glob('*.pdf'):
        fields = pdf_form_field_values(pdf_path)
        writer.write(fields)
```

I haven't tested this code so there may be some slight errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter you should do `writer.writeheader()` in order to get file with header

Comment: @Daweo apologies, I misremembered. Will correct soon.